# SQL Counting Duplicates in a Column

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have been stuck on this problem for a while and have searched over the net for an answer..

My problem is:

I have duplicates in one column. I want to count how many duplicates there are in the one column and then I want to divide the a field by that count. I want to be able to do this for each record in the column as well.

Basically I want the script to behave like this

Count number of duplicates -> divide field A by count of duplicates.

Sample data:

```
t1.Invoiceno | t2.Amount | t2.orderno
-------------------------------------
     201412       200      P202
     201412       200      P205
     302142       500      P232
     201412       300      P211
     450402       250      P102
     450402       250      P142
     450402       250      P512
```

Desired Result:

```
Invoiceno | Amount | orderno| duplicates|amount_new
-------------------------------------------------
 201412       200      P202        2       100
 201412       200      P205        2       100
 302142       500      P232        1       500
 201552       300      P211        1       300
 450402      1200      P102        3       400
 450402      1200      P142        3       400
 450402      1200      P512        3       400
```

I do not want to insert new columns into the table, I just want the results to show the two new columns.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please see the revised original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select A / dups.dups
from t cross join
     (select count(*) as dups
      from (select onecol
            from t
            group by onecol
            having count(*) > 1
           ) o
     ) dups
```

EDIT:

Well, now that the problem is clarified to something more reasonable.  You can user a similar approach to the above, but the `dups` subquery needs to be aggregated by `invoice` and `amount`:

```
select amount / dups.dups as new_amount
from table t join
     (select invoice, amount, count(*) as dups
      from table t
     ) dups
     on t.invoice = dups.invoice and t.amount = dups.amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
Declare @tempTable Table (  ID int , A int)

INSERT INTO @tempTable  VALUES (1, 12)
INSERT INTO @tempTable  VALUES (1, 12)
INSERT INTO @tempTable  VALUES (2, 20)
INSERT INTO @tempTable  VALUES (2, 24)
INSERT INTO @tempTable  VALUES (2, 15)
INSERT INTO @tempTable  VALUES (3, 10)
INSERT INTO @tempTable  VALUES (5, 12)

-------------------------------------------

;WITH DupsCTE (ID, DuplicateCount) AS
(
    SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS DuplicateCount FROM @tempTable GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT t.ID, t.A,
    c.DuplicateCount, t.A / c.DuplicateCount AS ModifiedA
FROM 
    @tempTable t
    INNER JOIN DupsCTE c ON c.ID = t.ID
```